# Posting a new question related to an existing question

Tags: discussion

I found an existing post where I wanted to post another question regarding the replies. Is it ok to answer the existing post or would it be better to post a new question and reference the existing post?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, rod. Questions regarding the site itself should be posted to http://meta.stackoverflow.com, to keep the main site clear for actual programming questions.

Comment: @Rex, very well stated; thank you for being friendly to the noobs.

Comment: beginners, not noobs. This is not counterstrike. ;)

Comment: Good question, can't vote up yet here though

Answer (score 3):

So long as the question is truly different, ask a different question, while linking to the originally. Additionally, it is generally helpful if you explain why you're asking the new question. For example, what piece of your situation is different, or specifically what area do you need more detailed information on.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new question, and link to the reply you want to discuss.