# Asking for an update on a dated question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

How would I go about it? For example, I see a question asking "what is the fastest way to do x and y" and newer solutions have since become popular.

I do not want my question to be closed so I want to make sure I find out common practice first.

Comment: See here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21820/posting-a-new-question-related-to-an-existing-question for a solution

Comment: That question is a bit different but perhaps you're pointing to this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21820/posting-a-new-question-related-to-an-existing-question/21821#21821

Answer (score 1):

If you are aware of "a faster way to do x and y", I recommend answering the old post with the new, faster ways you have discovered.

In other words, why not simply update the question yourself by *answering it*?

Comment: Because sometimes the question has already been answered. And frankly, my goal is to get answers to questions and trying to revive a 2 year old question isn't going to do that :-/

Comment: @nimmy then you could do both -- answer the old question with new, better info, and link the answer to the new question as well. That's the best of both worlds.

Comment: that sounds reasonable to me. I like that.

Comment: @JeffAtwood And what about if we are looking an answer for a question that is clearly outdated ? Should we ask for update by commenting (ironically, like I'm doing right now), modify the question (saying what ?) or just re-ask the question on a separate thread ?